# Install windows updates remotely

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2012-r2, invoke-command

I have a power shell script to download and install windows updates on Windows server 2012 R2. The script is working fine when i login to the remote machine and execute the script. The script fails when i try tio install it via powershell using invoke command. When i use invoke command the script downloads the files without any issue but it never installs the files. Below is the script i have

```
$MSUs = @('https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/6/0/D60ED3E0-93A5-4505-8F6A-8D0A5DA16C8A/Windows8.1-KB2919442-x64.msu',
'https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/5/6/256CCCFB-5341-4A8D-A277-8A81B21A1E35/Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu',
'https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/5/6/256CCCFB-5341-4A8D-A277-8A81B21A1E35/Windows8.1-KB2932046-x64.msu',
'https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/5/6/256CCCFB-5341-4A8D-A277-8A81B21A1E35/Windows8.1-KB2934018-x64.msu',
'https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/5/6/256CCCFB-5341-4A8D-A277-8A81B21A1E35/Windows8.1-KB2938439-x64.msu'
)

foreach ($MSU in $MSUs) {
$FileName = "C:\Temp\$(Split-Path $MSU -Leaf)"
Write-Host "Downloading package: $(Split-Path $MSU -Leaf)"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($MSU, $FileName)
Write-Host "Installing package: $(Split-Path $MSU -Leaf)"
Start-Process wusa -ArgumentList "$FileName /quiet /norestart" -Wait
}
```

I try to execute the script with below command

```
Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName 10.xx.xx.xxx -ScriptBlock { C:\\Temp\\1_KB.ps1| write-host}
```

Comment: the remote computer already has the local ps1 file in `c:\temp`?

Comment: Below link helped me in fixing the issue   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/2c6e154d-e497-46f0-aebd-925a113671e1/installing-standalone-windows-update-msu-packages?forum=ITCG

Comment: Did you try this? Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName 10.xx.xx.xxx -filepath C:\\Temp\\1_KB.ps1| write-host